# Jquery, php ajax post 500 Internal Server Error returns

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have some problem with jquery ajax & php. I'm not good in php, but I have to create a login page with php.

The promblem is, when I try to get some information from the server I get server error insted of the value.

Here is my php code (if someone know better method to create login on server side, please correct me):

```
<?php
//$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('A kapcsolódás nem sikerült: '+mysql_error());
$link = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "qm", "supersecret") or die("Nem sikerült kapcsolódni az adatbázishoz!"+mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
mysql_select_db("qm", $link);
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM felhasznalok WHERE nev ='{$uname}' AND jelszo = Sha1('{$pass}')") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($fetch) == 1) {
    $a = array();
    $['true'] = 'true';
    echo json_encode($a);
}else{
    $a = array();
    $['true'] = 'true';
    echo json_encode($a);
}
?>
```

And here is the code of the login on the client side:

```
function handleLogin(){
var _url = preUrl + "login.php";
var name = $("#loginForm #name").val();
var pass = $("#loginForm #pass").val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: _url,
    data: {name: name, pass: pass},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    beforeSend: function(){
        if((!name) || (!pass)){
            notify('error','Kérlek tölts ki minden adatot!');
            return false;
        }else{
            $("#loginForm #loginBtn").prop("disabled", true);  
        }
    },
    success: function(data){
    if(data[0].true == 'true'){
            window.localStorage["username"] = name;
            window.localStorage["password"] = pass;  
            $.mobile.changePage("#wall",{transition:"slide", reverse:false});
        }else{
            $('#loginForm #name').val("");
            $('#loginForm #pass').val("");
            notify('error','Hibás adatok!');
        }
    },
    error: function(err){
    //átírni ha a cordovajs be lesz szúrva!!!
    alert('Hiba: '+err.message);
}
});

$("#loginForm #loginBtn").prop("disabled", false);
return false;
}
```

I tried it out on different servers but nothing changed. I only get the error.

Comment: It can be error in server php script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo:

```
$['true'] = 'true';
```

Should probably be

```
$a['true'] = true;
```

(note the $ **a** )

Also note that whether your login would succeed or not, it will always fill that 'true value' with **true**. Looking at your Javascript, that's not what you want. Consider setting it on **false** in your else statement.

Comment: ohh, yes. I was careless. The error is not appeared. Don't you know why can I get back syntax error in this response? 

{"true":false}

Answer (score 2):

learn basic php: `$['true'] = 'true';` is a flat-out syntax error. this is the most likely cause of your server 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

Add string like that to see errors in your php script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log', 'path_to_log_file');
ini_set('log_errors_max_len', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', true);
```